# How to shade ImageView based on percentage of work done

Tags: android

In my app I have `ImageView` which has a background image already set on it, Now on completion of certain work 
depending on % of work done, I want to show some portion of `ImageView` shaded, I mean to say if 20% portion of work 
is done I want to shaded 20% of image view, similarly on 50%  of work I want to show 50% of `ImageView` shaded

So how can that be done?

Comment: do you mean transparency of the image or height of the image ?

Comment: Any solution you got ?

Answer (score 2):

You can override `onDraw()` of your `ImageView` to draw a semi-transparent rectangle on top of it with size equal to the `ImageView` and its width is a function of the progress.

Comment: As i have the same requirement, Can you please explain or give few more hints?